# Display Local Time from Parse SDK date

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, nsdate

I was wondering if I could somehow **use the local timezone via the user's phone to convert the when the game starts for them (i.e. 9 if they are EST, 8 if they are CST, etc.)**

I currently get the local time from the users phone:

```
    let gmtTime = NSDate()
```

Then use that time to only display items in the **present or future**:

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "data")
    query.orderByAscending("dateGame")
    query.whereKey("dateGame", greaterThanOrEqualTo: gmtTime)
```

Using the `dateGame` (which is in UTC time) from my Parse backend:

[image]
Instead of having to hardcode one standard timezone `time` for every game start (9 EST):

[image]

Any ideas if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/) can help you convert the start time to the user's local timezone.

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h z"
let startTime = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateGame)
```